# Filtering on a pandas column which is the difference between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas table which shows 2 dates and the duration between them:

```
|   date1    |   date2    | duration |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 10/04/2018 | 15/05/2018 |   5 days |
| 23/04/2018 | 28/04/2018 |   5 days |
| 27/11/2018 | 28/11/2018 |   1 days |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

duration column is generated by `df['duration'] = df['date2'] - df['date1']`

if I try to filter for durations lower than 5 for example:
`df.query('duration < 5')`
this fails as it it trying to filter a datetime object on an int.

What is the best way to get around this? setting 5 as as datetime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.dt.days` accessor on `timdelta` values to get number of days as integer value, then you can compare it against another number.

```py
>>> df.query('duration.dt.days < 5')
       date1      date2 duration
2 2018-11-27 2018-11-28   1 days
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  as a follow up is it possible to get all rows where duration is less than 5 or NaT? i.e. when either date1/date2 is not filled in and is NaT?

Comment: Yeah, you can combine the two conditions, something like: `df.query('(duration.dt.days < 5)  or (@pd.notna(duration)')`